# Как получить доступ к элементам управления внутри usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 формы, которые я засунул в UserControl
и есть Grid, куда я добавляю UserControl-ы как дочерний элемент, в зависимости от выбора в ComboBox

Мне нужно достать значения и имена TextBox-ов из UserContolol-ов.
Код:
MainWindow.XAML

```
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="FormType" SelectionChanged="FormType_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
        <Grid Name="FormContent" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,50,0,0" Height="261" Width="770"/>
        <Button Name="StartButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,103" Content="START" Click="StartButton_Click"></Button>
        <Button Name="StopButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="100,0,0,103" Content="STOP" Click="StopButton_Click" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    UserControl view_form;
    string form = "yaw emulator";
    string[] device_list = { "yaw emulator", "6dof" };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (string item in this.device_list)
        {
            FormType.Items.Add(item);
        }
        FormType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.MakeContentForm();
    }

    private void MakeContentForm()
    {
        FormContent.Children.Clear();
        if (this.form == "6dof")
        {
            this.view_form = new device_form_6dof();
        }
        else if (this.form == "yaw emulator")
        {
            this.view_form = new device_form_yaw_emulator();
        }
        else
        {
            this.view_form = new device_form_yaw_emulator();
        }
        this.view_form.Name = "View_Form";

        FormContent.Children.Add(view_form);
    }

    private void FormType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;

        this.form = text;
        this.MakeContentForm();
    }
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = FormContent.Children[0];
        //this.player = new MovePlayer();
        //this.device.start();

        //this.player.Start(this.device);
        this.StartButton.IsEnabled = false;
        this.StopButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

один из UserControl-ов (они отличаются только количеством полей)

device_form_6dof.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="COM port name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Margin="116,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="COM1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Name="port_name" TextChanged="port_name_TextChanged"/>
    <Label Content="Baudrate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Margin="116,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9600" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" MaxLength="6" Name="baudrate_tb" TextChanged="baudrate_tb_TextChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

в коде device_form_6dof.xaml.cs пока только заглушки - там показывать нечего...

Мне же нужно при нажатии Start получить данные полей UserControl-а, который сейчас активен.

Нашел по [ссылке](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5931b06-c913-4f69-b36c-6255961f000e/how-to-access-controls-inside-a-usercontrol?forum=csharplanguage) что то похожее, но не совсем понял.

UPD:
По идее, я сохраняю какой именно UserControl я использую на форме в поле view_form и могу обратиться к нему из любой точки в MainWindow. По идее, это поле типа UserControl
[Вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) указано, что я могу получить все, что мне надо, используя свойство Controls.
Но я почему то не могу к нему обратиться... Эхх.. пока единственный вариант, который я вижу - создать родительский класс для подобных UserControl-ов с реализацией метода возврата всех необходимых полей со значениями... но не хочется изобретать велосипед. Мне кажется, что все что нужно, где то там есть.

UPD2: Про Controls - не верно. По ссылке UserControl из пространства System.Windows.Forms, а я создавал, которые из пространства System.Windows.Controls.

РЕШЕНИЕ: спасибо товарищу Макс Жуков - помог очень сильно.
Исходник ответа нашел по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type/978352#978352) Там приводится простой и понятный новичку метод.
Что с ним делать? Я держу статический класс utils для таких целей.

```
namespace rServer
{
    static class utils
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

затем, в MainWindow.xaml.cs там, где необходимо произвожу вызов следующим образом

```
foreach (TextBox tb in utils.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>('Имя_элемента_по_которому_ищем'))
        {
            Console.Write(tb.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(tb.Text);
        }
```

Comment: А что у вас выводится в консоли?

Comment: это вместо дебага:) выводились имена текстовых полей и текст, который в них поместил пользователь (в данном случае - я)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи нужно:

1. Получить все `TextBox`'ы из вашего `UserControl`. Для этого пригодится `VisualTreeHelper` и простой extension-метод:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<T> GetControls<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
   {
       if (depObj == null) 
           return null;

       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
       {
          var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
          var result = (child as T) ?? GetControls<T>(child);
          if (result != null) 
              return result;

          return null;
      }
   }
   ```
2. После этого вы можете получить коллекцию TextBox'ов из вашего Grid'а:

   ```
   IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = 'имя_вашего грида'.GetControls<TextBox>();
   ```

И, соответственно, пробегом по коллекции опрашивать нужные вам поля:

```
foreach(TextBox tb in textBoxes)
{
   //tb.'имя_свойства'
}
```

Comment: Простите, а extension метод куда добавлять? я просто не так давно на C# пишу - многих тонкостей еще не понимаю... Я понимаю, что этот метод вызывается на гриде, но добавлять же его не к гриду надо, так? И ,если я правильно понял, вместо GetChildOfType должен быть рекурсивный вызов GetControls?

Comment: По поводу рекурсивного вызова - вы абсолютно правы, код я копировал из своего проекта, забыл исправить. Обновил ответ. Для extension-метода сделайте отдельный static-класс в нужной вам библиотеке.

Comment: Спасибо большое. С помощью вашего примера вышел на первоисточник.
Если что - ссылка - там немного другое использование, более понятный новичкам но пример идентичен. В целом, в проекте я специально держу для подобных целей статический класс utils и просто добавил этот метод в класс utils.
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type/978352#978352)

Comment: Отлично, рад помочь.